# Reorder_within not being cohesive between facets

Tags: r

I'm having trouble using facet_wrap and reorder_within. I want to reorder all of the bar graphs within in facet to be in decreasing order of frequency.

Here is my current code:

```
library(tidytext); library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=graphs_facet, aes(x = reorder_within(Type, frequency, Article.Categorization), y = frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  labs(x = "Graphs produced from analysis", y = "Frequency") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_text(aes(label=frequency), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, vjust = 0.9,hjust = 0.75, color = "black", size = 10), 
        axis.title = element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black")) +
  scale_x_reordered(labels = reorder_func) +
  facet_wrap(~as.factor(Article.Categorization))
```

But, it gives this output:
[image]

Obviously that isn't the output I want. Why is it considering that the bar graphs are separate for each Article when they have the same Type name?

Here is my data:

```
graphs_facet <- tibble::tibble(
  Article.Categorization = factor(rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4"), each = 11L)),
  Type = rep(
    c(
      "Violin Plots", "Line Graphs", "Bar Charts", "Scatterplots", "Histograms",
      "Heat Maps", "Time-Series", "Box Plots", "Pie Charts", "Specialized Graphs",
      "Brain Scans/Slices"
    ),
    4
  ),
  frequency = c(
    7L, 39L, 40L, 28L, 10L, 38L, 23L, 18L, 10L, 42L, 28L, 6L, 29L,
    30L, 25L, 10L, 34L, 22L, 12L, 3L, 27L, 16L, 2L, 21L, 24L, 13L,
    7L, 32L, 19L, 9L, 2L, 13L, 20L, 4L, 37L, 36L, 29L, 5L, 33L, 13L,
    16L, 5L, 24L, 47L
  ),
)
```

Basically, I want to have each facet with the bar graphs in order of highest to lowest frequency. But, I don't want them to be all spread out and weird. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by `-frequency` or `desc(frequency)` to get in decreasing order. And you need `scales = "free_x"` in your `facet_wrap` if you want each facet to only show the x values that pertain to it.

```
library(tidytext); library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=graphs_facet, aes(x = reorder_within(Type, -frequency, Article.Categorization), y = frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  labs(x = "Graphs produced from analysis", y = "Frequency") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_text(aes(label=frequency), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, vjust = 0.9,hjust = 0.75, color = "black", size = 10), 
        axis.title = element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black")) +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~Article.Categorization, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]